# Derivation of the Bandwidth formula for noninverting opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to find why the bandwidth formula in a close loop noninverting opamp is:
$$f=f_{unity} *B$$

I tried to prove the equation above by using the formula for close loop gain and the midband equation, the steps are:

- Find the open loop gain \$A_{OL} \$ when the close loop gain is \$\frac{1} {\sqrt2} \$ of its max close loop gain:
  $$\frac{A_{CL}} {\sqrt2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2*B}=\frac{A_{OL}}{1+A_{OL}B}$$
  $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2*B}=\frac{A_{OL}}{1+A_{OL}B}$$
  $$A_{OL} =\frac{1}{B(\sqrt2-1)}$$
- Next, find the frequency "f" in which the max open loop gain \$A_{max} \$ will be equal to the value of the open loop gain equation above(using midband equation) :
  $$A_{OL} =\frac{1}{B(\sqrt2-1)}=\frac{A_{max}} {\sqrt{1+(f/f_2)^2}}$$
  *(simplifying.....)*
  $$f=f_2*\sqrt{(A_{max}*B*(\sqrt2-1))^2-1}$$
- Next,I add \$A_{max} \$ to both numerator and denominator so that I will have an \$f_{unity} \$ at my equation, I will also move \$A_{max} \$ inside the squareroot:
  $$f=A_{max} *f_2*\frac{\sqrt{(A_{max}*B*(\sqrt2-1))^2-1}} {A_{max}} $$
  $$f=f_{unity}*\sqrt{(\frac{A_{max}*B*(\sqrt2-1)} {A_{max}})^2-\frac{1}{A_{max}^2}}$$
- Since \$A_{max} \$ is super large, I can cancel some values and the result will be:
  $$f=f_{unity} *B(\sqrt2-1)$$
  **Why do I have an excess \$sqrt2-1\$ in my formula? Where did I go wrong?**

Comment: I must admit - I did not go through the whole calculation. However, perhaps the following information helps: The closed-loop bandwidth is always identical to the frequency where the loop gain Aol*k is unity (k=feedback factor).

Comment: In your first bulleted equation, \$\frac{A_{CL}} {\sqrt2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2*B}=\frac{A_{OL}}{1+A_{OL}B}\$, \$\small A_{OL}\$ and \$\small A_{CL}\$ are complex functions of frequency. However \$\frac{1}{B\sqrt2}\$ is not a function of frequency. So is the simplification valid as frequency increases way beyond the open loop bandwidth frequency?

Comment: @LvW why does Aol*k is unity at the close loop bandwidth? I simulated it and as you have said the close loop bandwidth is really identical to the frequency when AOL*k is unity but I don't get why?

Comment: @Iwatani Naofumi...For a circuit with negative feedback the denominator is always (1-LG). This expression shows that the magnitude of the denominator is SQRT(2) for |LG|=1.

Comment: @LvW I'm sorry, it seems I'm still lacking some knowledge at negative feedback but what expression have a 1-LG as its denominator? I only have known \$A_{CL} =\frac{A_{OL}} {1+LG}\$

Comment: (1-LG) is the general formula with LG being negative for negative feedback. Using (1+LG) we do not include the negative sign at the summing junction in the loop gain expression. But it should always be included because each loop gain measurement/simulation will contain the minus sign  - and sometimes other components or blocks contain the minus sign (and NOT the summing junction). Example: A composize opamp combination can contain an inverter in the feedback loop - and the feedback path is connected to the non-inv. input of the main opamp..

Comment: So it's the same expression. But how would a \$\sqrt2\$ will be formed in \$A_{CL} =\frac{A_{OL}} {1+LG}\$? It will just be  \$A_{CL} =\frac{A_{OL}} {2}\$ not \$A_{CL} =\frac{A_{OL}} {\sqrt2}\$ if ever LG is unity. What am I missing, sir?

Comment: @LvW I think the fact that **the closed-loop bandwidth is always identical to the frequency where the loop gain \$A_{OL} *k\$ is unity** is an important piece to derive the bandwidth formula. I want to know the specific formula/expression that will result in a denominator of \$sqrt2\$ when LG is 1.Please,lend me your wisdom

Comment: The open-loop gain can be approximated as a simplified first-order model (intergator): Aol=wt/s (wt=transitfrequency). Hence the loop gain for negative feedback (k=feedback factor) is LG=-k*Aol=-k*wt/s=-k*wt/jw=+jk*wt/w. There is one frequency where w=k*wt with LG=+j and the magnitude |LG|=1. Hence, the magnitude of the closed-loop gain`s denominator is |D|=SQRT(1+1)=SQRT(2). This defines the 3-dB frequency for the closed-loop gain.

Comment: Got it now, thanks